# Django. Sentry. How can I pass user agent info into using sentry sdk?

Tags: python, django, logging, sentry

I use this code to setup sentry sdk

```
sentry_sdk.init(
    sentry_dsn,
    environment=sentry_env,
    release=release,
    send_default_pii=True,
    integrations=[
        LoggingIntegration(event_level=WARNING),
        DjangoIntegration(),
        CeleryIntegration(),
    ],
)
```

Usage of `send_default_pii=True` helped me to send user info, but browser still unknown
[(img with that view)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHvh3.png)

request.header contains the User-Agent param

Answer (score 0):

The user agent is parsed serverside (on sentry.io) from the User-Agent header. If the user agent is not recognized please file a bug against Sentry that includes the concrete value and possibly a link to the issue.

Comment: I can't find tag name for the user agent (https://docs.sentry.io/enriching-error-data/context/?platform=python). I was about to pass it by myself, but I can't find the key

Comment: I think this information can make this question more clearly